# Variable height NSTextField with PXListView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

I am trying to use `PXListView` to show a table of cells containing `NSTextField`s and I want to vary the height of each cell to fix the text within it.

On my subclassed cell view I have a height method that calculates the height the cell should be:

```
- (CGFloat)height{
    NSRect textRect = [self.text.attributedStringValue
                       boundingRectWithSize:NSMakeSize(NSWidth(self.text.frame), 0.0f) 
                       options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin];
    return MAX(90.0f, NSHeight(textRect)+73.0f);
}
```

Then on my `PXListViewDelegate`'s `heightOfRow` method I get the cell for the row then get the height of that cell:

```
- (CGFloat)listView:(PXListView *)listView heightOfRow:(NSUInteger)row{
    CustomViewCell *cell = (CustomViewCell *)[listView cellForRowAtIndex:row];
    return [cell height];
}
```

The problem is that cell is always `null`, I believe this is because I have a chicken or the egg scenario. The cell is null because `cellForRow` is never called because the height is zero so no cell need to be loaded.

What is the correct way to vary the height of a `PXListView` cell based on the text within it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to use the width of the table view to calculate the height of each table cell:

```
- (CGFloat)listView:(PXListView *)listView heightOfRow:(NSUInteger)row{
    NSRect textRect = [self.text.attributedStringValue
                       boundingRectWithSize:NSMakeSize(NSWidth(self.tableView.frame), 0.0f) 
                       options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin];
    return MAX(90.0f, NSHeight(textRect)+73.0f);
}
```